# Why i am get error when I trigger my build pipeline No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am working in Azure DevOps CICD pipeline. I have created an agent in Default Pool which is a Self-Hosted Agent.

My Agent Details:

**Agent.Name:** Deployment-Agent
**Agent.Version:** 2.210.1

Below is my yaml file:

```
trigger: none

variables:
- name: solution
  value: 'MyApp.sln'
- name: buildPlatform
  value: 'Any CPU'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: "npm_config_cache"
  value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

stages:
- stage: StartAzVMAgent
  jobs:
  - job: MsHostedAgentJobStartAzVM
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Azure CLI
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "Az-DevOps-AgentManager"
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az --version
          az account show
          az vm start --name  MyDeployment-Agent --no-wait --resource-group MyDeployment

- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      name: Default
      demands:
      - Agent.Name -equals Deployment-Agent
    steps:
     - task: Npm@1
       displayName: Install Node dependencies (packages)
       inputs:
         command: custom
         customCommand: install --save --legacy-peer-deps 
         workingDir: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'
        
     - task: Npm@1
       displayName: Install Node dependencies (packages)
       inputs:
         command: custom
         customCommand: install sweetalert2 file-saver 
         workingDir: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'
         
    - task: Cache@2
      displayName: Cache npm
      inputs:
        key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/package-lock.json'
        restoreKeys: |
          npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
        path: $(npm_config_cache)
    - script: npm ci

    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Building Client App
      inputs:
        script: node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build  --configuration production --aot --build-optimizer=true --common-chunk=true  --named-chunks=false --optimization=true --vendor-chunk=true --progress=true
        workingDirectory: 'MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp'
        
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Client Project'
      inputs:
        Contents: |
          MyApp.WebUI\MyClientApp\dist\**
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/client'
        flattenFolders: false
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use .NET 6.0
      inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: '6.0.x'
          installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
          
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
        zipAfterPublish: true
        arguments: '--output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/api'

    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Create EF Scripts
      inputs:
        script: |
          dotnet ef migrations add  FreshDb_08022021  -c MyAppDbcontext
          dotnet ef migrations script   --idempotent  --output migrations.sql --project MyApp.Persistence/MyApp.Persistence.csproj --context MyAppDbContext
   
   - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy EF Scripts to Staging'
      inputs:
        Contents: "**\\migrations.sql \n"
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        flattenFolders: true
  
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: StoptAzVMAgent
  dependsOn: __default
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: MsHostedAgentJobStopAZVm
    timeoutInMinutes: 0
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Azure CLI
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "Az-DevOps-AgentManager"
        scriptType: ps
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az --version
          az account show
          az vm deallocate --name MyDeployment-Agent --no-wait --resource-group MyDeployment
```

However i am getting the below error even when my agent is enabled and running.

**#Error:** No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: Use_for -equals Deployment-Agent, npm, Agent.Version -gtVersion **2.182.1**

Can I know from were does it takes this 2.182.1 as version as my agent version is higher than this but still it takes previous version and gives me error? Can anyone please help me on this as I am new to azure cicd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, please try the following steps:

1. Check the User capability of the "Use_for" in your agent.
2. Install the NPM in your agent and then restart the agent to scan the NPM.

For more information, you could refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

And install the NPM:https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

Comment: Thank You @Ging Yuan-MSFT so much for your answer. I followed the excat above steps for step 1 i used Agent.Name which i have updated  in the above yaml script and then went on and installed npm in my agent machine.
Actually node and npm was installed but it it was a user specific installation. Therefore, i installed node and npm globally and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add the very first task:

```
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Installing Node.JS  
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '16.x'
```